# Вытеснение элементов на сетке с минимальным количеством пустых ячеек

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, логика, фреймворк

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли алгоритмы или готовые решения по вытеснению элементов внутри сетки, чтобы элементы которые были вытеснены занимали места на сетке с минимальным количеством пустых ячеек.

Например:

Было
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрали на 9. Блок с 1 уменьшился до одной ячейки. А блок с 9 увеличился до шести клеток.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. необходимо раскидать элементы которые были вытеснены по освободившимся местам.

Comment: Вы хотите сами написать такую штуку или готовой воспользоваться тоже норм? Если норм, то возьмите masonry, оно такое умеет.

Comment: Без разницы. Лучше готовый фреймворк. Пробовал Masonry и Isotope. Есть некоторая проблема. Мне надо не вылезать за пределы сетки и когда я нажимаю на элемент он должен увеличится в пределах курсора, а остальные элементы вытеснить.

Comment: Я не совсем понял задачу. Во-первых, я не понимаю, что нужно:  реализация графики или логики (какие блоки нужно уменьшить). Во-вторых, непонятно, сколько может быть блоков, как они организованы и в каком формате заданы. Также я не понял примера: осталась пустая ячейка рядом с 9, 8 и 10.

Comment: Только логики. Графика мне важна. То есть как увеличить блок при наведении, прежний активный уменьшить, а те блоки, которые были затронуты при увеличении, расставить по свободным позициям с минимальными перестановками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Получение состояния в которое необходимо перейти  */
function getTransition(state, selected) {
    /* Переходы */
    var transition = {
        /* Текущие состояние */
        1: {
            /* В какое состояние перейти */
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        2: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        3: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        4: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 14,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        5: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        6: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        7: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        8: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        9: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 18
        },
        10: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        11: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        12: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        13: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        14: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 14,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        15: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        16: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        17: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        18: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 18
        },
        19: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        20: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        21: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        22: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 23,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        23: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 23,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        }
    };

    return transition[state][selected];
}

/* Получение конкретного состояния по его идентификатору */
function getStatesByItem(id) {
    /* Состояния элементов при выбранном активном элементе */
    var states = {
        /* Порядковые номера для состояний */
        1: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        2: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        3: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-2 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-1 col-2',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        4: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-2 col-2',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-3 col-1',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        5: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-2 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        6: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        7: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        8: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-2 col-3'
        },
        9: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-3',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-3 col-2'
        },
        10: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-3',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        11: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-2 col-3',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-1 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        12: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-2 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-3 col-3',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        13: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-3',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        14: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-1',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        15: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        16: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        17: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-3 col-4'
        },
        18: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-3 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-2 col-2'
        },
        19: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-2',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        20: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        21: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-2 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        22: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-4 col-2',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        23: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-2 col-2',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        }
    };
    return states[id];
}

/* Установка состояний элементов по конкретному элементу  */
function setStatesByItem(coord) {
    for (var key in coord) {
        if (coord.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            jQuery('#' + key).addClass(coord[key]);
        }
    }
}

/* Функция, которая выполняется на месте её вызова */
(function (jQuery)
{
    /* Прототоп jQuery для уменьшения элементов */
    jQuery.fn.elementsToSmall = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('big');
        });
    };

    /* Прототоп jQuery для увеличения элемента */
    jQuery.fn.elementToBig = function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('big');
    };

    /* Прототоп jQuery для установки позиций элементов */
    jQuery.fn.setPosition = function (state) {
        jQuery('.box').each(function () {

            /* Сбросить текущие координаты по строкам */
            jQuery(this).removeClass(function (index, className) {
                return (className.match(/(^|\s)row-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });

            /* Сбросить текущие координаты по столбцам */
            jQuery(this).removeClass(function (index, className) {
                return (className.match(/(^|\s)col-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
        });

        /* Получить новые координаты элементов по текущему состоянию */
        var coordinates = getStatesByItem(state);

        /* Установить новые координаты */
        setStatesByItem(coordinates);

    };
})(jQuery);

/* Работаем с данными после того, как структура страницы сформирована */
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    /* Текущее состояние по умолчанию */
    var state = 1;

    /* Обработчики элементам с классом box при наведении */
    jQuery('.box').mouseenter(function () {

        /* Получить идентификаторы выбранного элемента */
        var selectedItem = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        /* Получаем состояние в которое необходимо перейти */
        state = getTransition(state, selectedItem);

        /* Уменьшаем все элементы кроме текущего */
        jQuery('.box').not(this).elementsToSmall();

        /* Увеличиваем текущий элемент */
        jQuery(this).elementToBig();

        /* Устанавливаем элементам положение на сетке */
        jQuery(this).setPosition(state);

    });

});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.text {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.containerbox {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.containerbox .box {
  display: table;
  width: 198px;
  height: 118px;
  background-color: #cfe7f5;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.containerbox .box.merge-col {
  height: 238px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-not {
  left: -400px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-1 {
  left: 0;
}
.containerbox .box.col-2 {
  left: 200px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-3 {
  left: 400px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-4 {
  left: 600px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-not {
  top: -360px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-1 {
  top: 0;
}
.containerbox .box.row-2 {
  top: 120px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-3 {
  top: 240px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-4 {
  top: 360px;
}
.containerbox .box.big {
  width: 398px;
  height: 358px;
  background-color: #83caff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.containerbox .description {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.js"></script>
        <title>Меню из изображений для сайта</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="containerbox">
                <div id="autohydraulic" class="box big row-1 col-1">
                    <span class="description">1</span>
                </div>
                <div id="onboardcars" class="box row-1 col-3">
                    <span class="description">2</span>
                </div>
                <div id="sleepcabins" class="box row-1 col-4">
                    <span class="description">3</span>
                </div>
                <div id="dumpers" class="box row-2 col-3">
                    <span class="description">4</span>
                </div>
                <div id="airports" class="box merge-col row-2 col-4">
                    <span class="description">5</span>
                </div>
                <div id="trailers" class="box row-3 col-3">
                    <span class="description">6</span>
                </div>
                <div id="cranes" class="box row-4 col-1">
                    <span class="description">7</span>
                </div>
                <div id="tugboats" class="box row-4 col-2">
                    <span class="description">8</span>
                </div>
                <div id="firetrucks" class="box row-4 col-3">
                    <span class="description">9</span>
                </div>
                <div id="doublerowcabins" class="box row-4 col-4">
                    <span class="description">10</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```